# 12V battery - T1 vs F1 terminals

Tags: batteries, connector, cables

I recently purchased three 12V batteries: [#1](http://www.batteryspace.com/SLA-Battery-Sealed-Lead-Acid-Battery-12V-4.5AH.aspx), [#2](http://www.batteryspace.com/sealedleadacidbattery12v12ah144whforupsseascootere-bikes.aspx), and [#3](http://www.batteryspace.com/sealedleadacidbattery12v75ah20hrsforupsseascooterande-bikes.aspx).

They all say that they have T1 terminals; however, when looking for the appropriate connectors for my 18 AWG wire, I could really only found information about F1 and F2 terminals.  Based on [this page](http://www.batterystuff.com/kb/articles/battery-articles/terminal-type-f1-f2-tabs.html), two of my batteries definitely have F2 connectors and one definitely has F1 connectors.

So what's the deal with T1 (and T2?) versus F1 and F2?  Are they the same?  Perhaps T refers to the wire connector while F refers to the battery terminal?

Comment: Batteries: [1](http://www.batteryspace.com/SLA-Battery-Sealed-Lead-Acid-Battery-12V-4.5AH.aspx), [2](http://www.batteryspace.com/sealedleadacidbattery12v12ah144whforupsseascootere-bikes.aspx), [3](http://www.batteryspace.com/sealedleadacidbattery12v75ah20hrsforupsseascooterande-bikes.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the T1, F1 etc nomenclature - I've seen various terms used for this type of connector including *blade*, *spade* and *[tab](http://uk.rs-online.com/web/c/connectors/terminals-splices/crimp-tab-terminals/)*, but whatever you call them, these terminals and the corresponding receptacles are available in different widths and thicknesses and the safest way to specify them is by width and thickness - for all three of your batteries that's 4.75 x 0.8 mm, according to the web pages you have linked to.

The most common type of wire connector for these terminals would be a [crimp receptacle](http://uk.rs-online.com/web/c/connectors/terminals-splices/crimp-receptacles/) and for these you'd also need to specify the wire diameter that it is to crimp on to.